# JQuery Datatable having trouble with binding multiple events with multiple buttons in single row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very new to JQuery, I have a data table integrated in my application.
I have added two buttons in the last column, but facing issues with binding it with particular event.

Here is my code to generate last column of the table.

```
   "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<');
    console.log(full);
    if(full.status) {
        return '<button href="#"' + 'id="'+ data + '">Edit</button> <input type="button" href="#"' + 'id="disable-'+ data + '" value="Disable"></input>';                       
    }
    else {
        return '<button href="#"' + 'id="'+ data + '">Edit</button> <input type="button" href="#"' + 'id="enable-'+ data + '" value="Enable"></input>';
    }
}
```

based on status I am showing button either enable/disable.

Now I want to bind onclick event using JQuery.

I have bind one button using following way.

```
$('#tenantTable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {        
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
});
$('#tenantTable tbody').on( 'click', 'input[id="enable*"]', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    console.log('>> DISABLE <<');
});
$('#tenantTable tbody').on( 'click', 'input[id="disable*"]', function () {
    var data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    console.log('>> DISABLE <<');
});
```

It is not working, Is there a way I can do the above?

Comment: Is the "way above" not working?

Comment: No it is not, no event is being fired when I click on the "Enable"/"disable" button.

Comment: I believe you only have to change: `'input[id="enable*"]'` to `'input[id*="enable"]'` and `'input[id*="disable"]'`

Comment: working :) :) thanks :) :) you can post your answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on()` method in this way is a good choice to delegate event handlers.
The selector parameter you use however should be changed slightly:

```
$('#tenantTable tbody').on( 'click', 'input[id*="enable"]', function () {
    // logic
});

$('#tenantTable tbody').on( 'click', 'input[id*="disable"]', function () {
    // logic
});
```

The `*=` selector translates in a **contains** selector.
An alternative for your solution could be a **startswith** selector `^=`

This logic makes it possible to have dynamic id's for example:

```
<input type="button" id="enable-5" data-action="enable" data-id="5" value="my button" />
```

The selector could be something like:

```
$(element).on('click', '[id^="enable-"]', function(){/*this: element where the id starts with enable-*/});
$(element).on('click', '[data-action="enable"]', function(){/*this: element where the data-action equals to enable*/});
$(element).on('click', '[data-id]', function(){/*this: element where data-id is defined*/});
```

Comment: can you please add some example for startsWith selector ?

Comment: I provided some examples as requested. Also a little hint to the idea of using data-attributes if more dynamics are required in the future.